# Convert a System::String into an int

Tags: c++-cli, picturebox

I am trying to read the value from a sensor an plot some figures depending on that value. I want to compare the value from the sensor to an int variable and I think this is my problem. This is what I am doing:

```
System::String ^leido=this->serialPort1->ReadLine();
Int32 tb1Int;
Int32 cien=0;
bool ret = Int32::TryParse(leido, tb1Int); 

//Drawing

if (tb1Int > cien){
PictureBox ^g = gcnew PictureBox;
g->Parent = this;
g->Location = Point(630,20);
g->Size::set(Drawing::Size(900,90));
g->BackColor::set(Color::Aquamarine);}
```

I am quite sure the problem is the comparision (tb1Int > cien). It should be fulfilled, but the code for drawing is not executed.

Any help??

Comment: What is in the string `leido`? Does `TryParse` return true? I'm guessing "garbage" and "no", respectively. Until you've fixed those, you shoudln't expect yourt drawing code to be triggered.

Comment: "leido" contains the value that has been read from the sensor and the return value for "TryParse" indicates whether the conversion succeeded, so it is "true"

Comment: Yes, I can actually read the code. Have you _actually checked the value_ in `leido`? If so, share it with us. If not, please go away and check.